# HTML Tag not allow in textbox

Tags: html, validation, tags

In my website contact form. I have received email. but there are some HTML tags included in email.

Can you please provide any solution like validation (special symbol are not allowed) etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this suits your needs.

You just need to add

```
required pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+"
```

attribute to your input-textbox.
This will allow upper-case/lower-case text, numbers  and spaces only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <form>
     <label>Name*</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" class="field" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" />
     <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me is there allow space. because some time user type sentence at that time space must be required.

Comment: Please see now.. it also accepts spaces... just need to add <empty space> to the regex pattern

Comment: Thank you. that's i want ya.

Comment: Anytime my friend.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate with javascript while submitting the form call below function onsubmit. like below.

```
function Validate() {

     str = (document.getElementById('TextBox')).value;
          if (str.match(/([\<])([^\>]{1,})*([\>])/i) == null) {

              // valid text entered
          }
          else {

              // not valid 
          }
      }
```